# SSIS package runs in Visual Studio but no longer runs in Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an Active Directory service account set up to run our SSIS packages. Let's call it DOMAIN\Sql_Agent_User. This account was incorrectly set up as a domain admin. We recently realized that and removed it from domain admins. Most permissions were otherwise set up properly, but one particular job that writes to a UNC path started failing. So we gave Sql_Agent_user read/write/modify to that particular folder (it previously had "Full control" there) last night, expecting it to work properly this morning.

Now I can log in to this SQL Server machine as Sql_Agent_User and run the package fine from Visual Studio. But when I try to run it using the SQL Agent, I get the following (edited) error message:

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\Sql_Agent_User. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute 
Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft
Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:38:01 AM  Error: 
2017-03-07 08:38:01.43     Code: 0xC001401E     Source: DTSXPackageName 
Connection manager "Data File"     Description: The file name 
"\\OtherMachine\Data\Shared\Folder\Hours.csv" specified in the connection 
was not valid.  End Error  Error: 2017-03-07 08:38:01.43     Code: 
0xC001401D     Source: DTSXPackageName      Description: Connection "Data 
File" failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2017-03-07 08:38:01.84     Code:
0xC001401E     Source: DTSXPackageName Connection manager "Data File"
Description: The file name "\\OtherMachine\Data\Shared\Folder\Hours.csv"
specified in the connection was not valid.  End Error  Error: 2017-03-07
08:38:01.87     Code: 0xC0202070     Source: DTSXPackageName Connection
manager "Data File"     Description: The file name property is not valid.
The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.  End Error  
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:38:01
AM  Finished: 8:38:01 AM  Elapsed:  0.844 seconds.  The package execution 
failed.  The step failed.
```

The UNC path does go to the correct file and this is the same file that is correctly output when I run the package in Visual Studio. I can navigate to that path using Windows Explorer when logged in as that service account user.

Again, the package has not changed at all. This looks like a permissions issue, but how?

Answer (score 0):

The security context does not have permission to the shared folder \othermachine...

A common solution is to create a proxy that has the correct permissions and run the job under the proxy.

Please see this how to do this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Here is really nice article about creating proxy account for SSIS:

https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/setting-up-a-proxy-account-to-run-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-2012-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the SQL Agent service fixed the issue. No proxy was needed as the account already had the required permissions, as evidenced by it running properly in Visual Studio.